# Context menu missing for OneDrive

Tags: windows-10, office365, uac, onedrive, context-menu

I have got a windows 10 pro workstation (not domain joined, version 1909) with two local user accounts. User-A (member of Users) and User-B (member of Administrators).

Both users have seperate Microsft 365 accounts and are using OneDrive. Now I realized that the context menu for User-A is missing, for User-B it's there.

[image]

I have worked through this Microsoft article ([How to change the User Account Control policies to allow OneDrive context menus](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-change-the-user-account-control-policies-to-allow-onedrive-context-menus-1f957672-848d-48bb-bfe8-5af828613211)). The `OneDrive.exe` process is not running elevated - not for User-A and not for User-B.

Also setting the suggested policies didn't make a change. I have even tried disabling UAC at all without luck. The running OneDrive version is 20.169.0823.0006 which should be the latest (as of writing).

So what the heck? How can I get the context menu for User-A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now I realized that the context menu for User-A is missing, for User-B
> it's there.

Most likely the issue is a damaged User Profile (for which there is not any fix in most cases).  Make yet another test Windows User Profile and test the context menu. Likely it will be working.

Assuming the above, make a complete backup of the contents of User A's profile (documents, email files, favorites and so on) to a neutral local like  c:\temp . Perhaps even make a copy of the profile to a USB hard drive for safety.

Now delete the User A profile, restart, set User A up again, and restore the contents of User A's profile.

Comment: Indeed, it was the user profile. I have switched the users profile to a Microsoft account, and voila everything working as expected. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your update and I was pleased to assist you